# Fastest "Match Option" in ARCGIS's "Spatial Join."

Tags: join, match, arcgis, esri

In ESRI's ARCGIS software, the Spatial Join tool has various "Match Options" for joining your data. I would like to know the most rapid and reliable Match Option for the following scenario:

Target features: Point Class
Join Features: Polygon class

-The points are within the polygons
-No polygons overlap
-All points are within a polygon
-Some polygons have many points

The ones I am considering (unless a different one is better) are:
Closest, Intersect, Within, and Have Their Centers In

Once I choose the fastest of those, will it be faster to include a search radius? Or is ARC smart enough that if you leave that blank it will assume a search radius of 0.

Comment: I think Intersect would be fine. Polygons cannot be Within or Have centers in points. I think http://gis.stackexchange.com/ is better for such questions.